# C# - Html Agility Pack - can't read from web

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to make a small program to read content from a wikipedia page, and to get the html, I found this code elsewhere on SO

```
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

        doc.LoadHtml("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The Metamorphosis of Prime Intellect");
        var text = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//body//text()").Select(node => node.InnerText);

        foreach (string line in text)
            output.AppendLine(line);

        string textOnly = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(output.ToString());

        Console.WriteLine(textOnly);
```

However, I'm getting a runtime error "ArgumentNullException was unhandled", and this line is highlighted:

```
        var text = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//body//text()").Select(node => node.InnerText);
```

Does anyone see the problem?

Answer (score 4):

`doc.LoadHtml` takes *html string* not *url*. To download that page you can use `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb` class

```
var web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
var doc = web.Load("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The Metamorphosis of Prime Intellect");

var text = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//body//text()").Select(node => node.InnerText);
var output = String.Join("\n", text);
```

`SelectNodes` returns 622 items in my test.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform the download yourself.

For example, you can use the [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class from the `System.Net` namespace:

```
var pageUri = new Uri("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The Metamorphosis of Prime Intellect");
var wc = new WebClient();
var html = wc.DownloadString(uri);

//Then do
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
```

There is also a [`HttpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx) class if you so desire.

These have an advantage over `HtmlWeb` that you can use them in [EAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wewwczdw.aspx) and C# 5 `async` operations.